# How to get current host name and path name on ajax calling c# method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages

jquery code is

```
 url: '/Jobseeker/Home/?handler=DetailHome_Jobs',
            type: "POST",
```

in code behind i am not getting current browser url like

```
http://localhost:44984/project-administrator-contract-jobs-in-India
```

i am getting a route url 'http://localhost:44984/Jobseeker/Home/'..
i face this issue only on ajax call method. code behind code is.

```
public PartialViewResult OnPostDetailHome_Jobs()
        {

             string url = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{ this.Request.Path}";
        .
        .
        .
        .
        }
```

i want to get a current url from ajax call method from code behind

```
http://localhost:44984/project-administrator-contract-jobs-in-India
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current page url  , you can get it from the `referer` header in the request like below:

```
public void OnPostDetailHome_Jobs()
{

    string url= Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

}
```

Result:
[image]